# Teamcity builds filling up disk space with clean up enabled

Tags: teamcity, node-modules, teamcity-9.0

I have a teamcity installation running on a windows server

I have a build process, that is building a .net application. As part of the build process it is running a gulp task, and is installing various node modules to build all the sass and js files.

Within my teamcity solution i have my clean up rules for "Everything" to be older that the 4th-th successful build

However teamcity does not appear to be cleaning everything up, because my artifacts folder is massive ( and caused the server to run out of disk space )

Now I believe that the issue is because one of the gulp task and all the node_modules being installed. Because of how nested node installs everything.

On windows machines, in most instances you cannot just delete a node_modules folder as you get the path longer than 256 char warning, and you have to use the robocopy trick of copying across an empty folder to delete the node_modules folder

What have others done to resolve this problem of artifacts not being correctly cleaned up ?

I was thinking about another step that would delete the node_modules folder from the artifact folder after the step to process the gulp tasks, but I cannot see in the list of teamcity parameters once that points to the artifact folder for the current build.

Comment: Have you considered to use the Swabra Build Feature ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear if the issue is with TeamCity clean-up not trying to delete the builds (I've addressed that in my answer), trying but failing to delete the artifacts (teamcity-server.log should have errors on that), or the files piling up on the agent machine (in which case it's up to your build to delete the files).  BTW, it's better to publish archives as artifacts instead of many files separately - it's faster and usually easier to use this way.

Answer (score 1):

If the builds should be deleted by the server clean-up, but you still see the builds in TeamCity UI and they are not pinned, the most common reason for that is having other builds snapshot- or artifact-depending on the builds in question. Check build's Dependencies tab and related [TeamCity settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Clean-Up#Clean-Up-Clean-upforDependentBuilds).

Comment: What would be the solution of that is the case? Snapshot dependencies are important and cannot be avoided. In that case, is TeamCity's clean-up functionality useless?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I am posting this as an answer because I came across this Q&A while trying to resolve a problem and this answer would have saved me hours.

**There are bugs in both TeamCity's clean-up rules and its documentation**, certainly for historical versions.

In particular, the behaviour to force snapshot dependency builds to be cleaned up did not work properly in earlier versions (before approx 2021.2), and this is not mentioned in the corresponding documentation.

This means that if you have a build configuration which is a snapshot dependency for another build, you may not be able to clean up build in the first configuration until its 'dependent' builds are fully deleted.

For (say) a unit test build, the logs and .NET coverage reports (stored as hidden artefacts) can easily stretch to tens of MB, crippling hard disk space for a busy server.

For full details, and links to the JetBrains bug tracker reports, see this Q&A on the JetBrains TeamCity forum:

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/17232521189394-Hidden-artifacts-not-being-cleaned-up?page=1#community_comment_17243897731218

**The only satisfactory workaround we found was to write and execute a completely manual clean-up script on the machine in question.** We used Python for this (clean-up script available on request) but obviously many alternatives exist.